# How to specify attributes on root element?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, for-xml-path, for-xml

### Short version

Using SQL Server `FOR XML ROOT('Customers')`, how to I add attributes to that root node?

```
<Customers> ← attributes here
   <Customer>Ian</Customer>
   <Customer>Shelby</Customer>
   <Customer>Dave</Customer>
</Customers>
```

### Long Version

When using `FOR XML` in SQL Server:

```
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES
    (122, 'All-Purpose Bike Stand'),
    (119, 'Bike Wash'),
    (115, 'Cable Lock')
) AS Products(ProductModelID, Name)
FOR XML PATH('Product')
```

it normally simply returns the elements:

```
<Product>
  <ProductModelID>122</ProductModelID>
  <Name>All-Purpose Bike Stand</Name>
</Product>
<Product>
  <ProductModelID>119</ProductModelID>
  <Name>Bike Wash</Name>
</Product>
<Product>
  <ProductModelID>115</ProductModelID>
  <Name>Cable Lock</Name>
</Product>

(3 rows affected)
```

That's not a valid XML document, because there are **three** *top-level nodes* - rather than just one.

That can be fixed by specifying `ROOT('RootNodeName')`:

```
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES
    (122, 'All-Purpose Bike Stand'),
    (119, 'Bike Wash'),
    (115, 'Cable Lock')
) AS Products(ProductModelID, Name)
FOR XML PATH('Product'), ROOT('Products')

<Products>
  <Product>
    <ProductModelID>122</ProductModelID>
    <Name>All-Purpose Bike Stand</Name>
  </Product>
  <Product>
    <ProductModelID>119</ProductModelID>
    <Name>Bike Wash</Name>
  </Product>
  <Product>
    <ProductModelID>115</ProductModelID>
    <Name>Cable Lock</Name>
  </Product>
</Products>

(3 rows affected)
```

Excellent.

### Except Attributes

The above is great, but I'm not done with the XML document I need to generate. I need add some attributes to the root node:

```
<Products operationalMode="Test" batchDate="2021-02-15T17:36:22" formatId="8e884ace-bee4-11e4-8dfc-aa07a5b093db">
  <Product>
    <ProductModelID>122</ProductModelID>
    <Name>All-Purpose Bike Stand</Name>
  </Product>
  <Product>
    <ProductModelID>119</ProductModelID>
    <Name>Bike Wash</Name>
  </Product>
  <Product>
    <ProductModelID>115</ProductModelID>
    <Name>Cable Lock</Name>
  </Product>
</Products>
```

How do I add attributes to the `XML ROOT('rootNode')` element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following solution.

XML should be at minimum **well-formed**. To be valid it needs an XML Schema.

It is not clear what is the source for the attributes, so I just hard-coded their values.

As you see, we need to apply `FOR XML PATH` clause twice. Once for the 'inner' XML. And second time for the root element, and specified attributes via aliases with at signs.

**SQL**

```
SELECT 'Test'AS [@operationalMode]
    , '2021-02-15T17:36:22' AS [@batchDate]
    , '8e884ace-bee4-11e4-8dfc-aa07a5b093db' AS [@formatId]
, (
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES
        (122, 'All-Purpose Bike Stand'),
        (119, 'Bike Wash'),
        (115, 'Cable Lock')) AS Products(ProductModelID, Name)
    FOR XML PATH('Product'), TYPE
)
FOR XML PATH('Products'), TYPE;
```

**Output**

```
<Products operationalMode="Test" batchDate="2021-02-15T17:36:22" formatId="8e884ace-bee4-11e4-8dfc-aa07a5b093db">
  <Product>
    <ProductModelID>122</ProductModelID>
    <Name>All-Purpose Bike Stand</Name>
  </Product>
  <Product>
    <ProductModelID>119</ProductModelID>
    <Name>Bike Wash</Name>
  </Product>
  <Product>
    <ProductModelID>115</ProductModelID>
    <Name>Cable Lock</Name>
  </Product>
</Products>
```